# App crashing in AsiHttprequest.m file

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiimage, asihttprequest

How to solve the crashing in **ASIHttpRequest.m** file.
I'm sending Uiimage to server by bytes format,

```
NSMutableData *imageData = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f) mutableCopy];
    [request setPostBody:imageData];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"fileName" value:[[imageArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] filename]];
 [request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

But app crashing fail with error method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting header of the image type.Just set Post header and responsetype header.And after getting image data just make it encoded.

Comment: But the server side they are getting the header response type.In stream format.

Comment: this is my crashing Line code in ASIHttpRequest.m file,if (theError && [theError code] != ASIAuthenticationErrorType && [theError code] != ASITooMuchRedirectionErrorType)

Comment: Which encoding you are using for image posting.?? They have to use the same encoder and decoder.

Answer (score 0):

you can try out of two method

```
[request setFile:@"File Path" withFileName:@"image.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"file"];

[request setData:Data withFileName:@"image.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"file"];
```

Comment: Its ok,but I need to post header data for this image.

Comment: this is my crashing Line code in ASIHttpRequest.m file,if (theError && [theError code] != ASIAuthenticationErrorType && [theError code] != ASITooMuchRedirectionErrorType)